# WebView and Mega (cloud) share page?

Tags: java, android, webview, webviewclient

I would like to manage a Mega file share homepage with a WebView and a WebViewClient.
The share URL is of type: https://mega.nz/file/vYFgUQKS#Wnyw--STwQxDNJ7NJN_x2DJbgZmcogn_yRIptbEIX4s

The page is displayed correctly in my Webview. This page displays a Download button.
When you click on the button, a progress bar appears and the download seems to be done "internally".
When the progress is complete, a save button appears.

My Problem: the action on the save button does not result in any method call of my WebViewClient:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
..... }
```

Nor the Download button for that matter. No way to download the file from my WebView.
Do you have an idea on how to proceed?